# What makes -"I did not like those" an improper answer?

Tags: personal-pronouns, demonstrative-pronouns

Here is the sentence I speak...

> She gave me chocolates, but I did not like *those*

Natives seem to prefer this with the objective case of 'they'...

> She gave me chocolates, but I did not like *them*

But all natives, do you agree on this?

> She gave me chocolates, but *<del>they</del> those* did not taste good

Comment: I'm confused using the pronoun here: Therefore, in order to engage people on the eCommerce websites, it is important to update THOSE/THEM on a regular basis. I'm talking about updating the sites and not the people visiting.

Comment: Hmm, I think you've slightly misunderstood. Nobody's said that *I did not like those* isn't proper English!

Comment: @Araucaria come on, now that's what a few (including you) users have been telling me all day :)

Comment: @MaulikV Absolutely not! We've just said that *them* is the normal unmarked pronoun for things and that *those* has a different, deictic meaning.

Comment: @Araucaria I'll be happy if you clarify this in the answer. For the sake of learning...I mean

Comment: As an aside, "weren't in good taste" means they went against the flow of decency and manners. _His joke was too vulgar for the party and was not in good taste._ If you're talking about chocolates or cupcakes, it should be: _She gave me chocolates, but they **didn't taste good**._

Comment: @MaulikV I couldn't write an answer as clear and helpful as StoneyB's below! :)

Comment: "weren't in good taste" is as @J.R. described above. "weren't good in taste" is not idiomatic.

Comment: @TimS. Though, "weren't good in taste" is clumsy, and invites the reader to autocorrect it to one of those other forms.

Comment: @J.R. That's why I like you, everyone here **and** above all, this ***lovely site***. How much you help people like me, you actually don't know. Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 19):

Whether *those* or *them* should be used depends on the context.

*This/these* and *that/those* are called *demonstratives*, from a Latin word meaning "point".<sup>†</sup> When you use them you are pointing emphatically to a particular object or set of objects, typically to distinguish that object or set from similar objects in the environment.

For instance, if a salesclerk shows you three shirts you might say "I like that one", indicating that you like one shirt better than the other two.

The "environment" also incudes the discourse context: what has been said previously. If you have not yet mentioned anything which might be confused with the object you are talking about, there is no need for a demonstrative, and you use the ordinary personal pronoun.

> Yesterday was my birthday, and Sarah and I went out for dinner. After dinner she gave me chocolates, but I didn't like them.

But if it is possible that your reader or hearer will misunderstand what *them* refers to, or if you want to make it clear that you are distinguishing its object from other objects in the discourse, you use a demonstrative.

> Yesterday was my birthday. Kevin gave me a flash drive, and Brad gave me a sweater. Sarah gave me chocolates, but I didn't like those.

Using *those* distinguishes the chocolates and implies that you *did* like the other gifts.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Araucaria uses the term *deictic*, which means basically the same thing; it comes from the Greek word for "point" rather than the Latin.</sub>

Comment: +1 Clear and very helpful. I tend to use the term *deictic* for that general pointy kind of property, but also, like you, use *demonstratives* to refer to these pronouns/determiners.

Comment: This is good one but **now** I'm curious about RuchirM's comment: "I'm confused using the pronoun here: Therefore, in order to engage people on the eCommerce websites, it is important to update THOSE/THEM on a regular basis. I'm talking about updating the sites and not the people visiting" What would you prefer there? Those/them?

Comment: The example that RuchirM contains two possible referents for a pronoun, one animate and the other inanimate. I think he's implying that if you use "them" in such a context, readers would interpret the pronoun as referring to the animate antecedent, so using "those" makes it clear that you meant the inanimate one.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock **EXACTLY** that's what I have been telling. 'Those' over 'them' for inanimate things. Do you see my point now?

Comment: @MaulikV *They* and *them* do not select for animacy as *who* and *whom* do. "Hey, where are my chocolates?" "I ate them."

Comment: @StoneyB I fully understand that but what do you think in RuchirM's case?

Comment: @MaulikV The problem there is structure, not the pronoun; it wants rewriting, with fewer words. "Websites should be updated, on a regular schedule, to engage people more fully."

Answer (score 1):

**Do you know the style of jeans that have a tapered leg?

--Oh yes, I like those.  I'm not fond of the ones with a flared leg.**

*Those* can refer to something in particular, distinguishing it from other things in its vicinity, whether literally or figuratively.

Figurative vicinity = similar.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "the style of jeans that HAS tapered LEGS ?

Comment: No, this is a conversation between one-legged pirates.